# Jstree - how to get children of a parent node (in other words, how to get siblings)

Tags: javascript, jstree

How to get all children of parent of currently selected node?

Something like currentNode._get_parent()._get_children() (which does not work)

Comment: Did you tri to search for the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511858/jstree-jquery-plugin-get-all-child-and-sub-child-nodes-of-parent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
jQuery.jstree._reference("#treeSelector")._get_children(parentNode);
```

also see [documentation](http://www.old.jstree.com/documentation/core)