# Get all descendants (children and sub-children and so on) of jstree3 node

Tags: jquery, jstree

How does one get all the descendants of a node in jstree3?

The jstree 1 technique of searching the dom does not work, e.g.: [jstree jquery plugin - Get all child and sub child nodes of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511858/jstree-jquery-plugin-get-all-child-and-sub-child-nodes-of-parent)

I have seen this question several times for jstree1.x, but for jstree3, things are a little different and the jstree1.x answers will confuse instead of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth bearing in mind that in jstree 3, selecting all the descendants, or any other select using the dom, will not yield the correct results because the child nodes are not merely hidden when closed, they do not exist

You can build this list of nodes yourself quite easily by traversing the jstree node tree. `inst` is a reference to your jstree instance. `nodes` is a closure which will store the results.

```
var nodes = [];

function traverse(state) {

    // Get the actual node
    var node = inst.get_node(state);

    // Add it to the results
    nodes.push(node);

    // Attempt to traverse if the node has children
    if (inst.is_parent(node)) {
        $.each(node.children, function(index, child) {
            traverse(child);
        });
    }
};

// Id of the node at which you wish to start the traverse (it will also
// be added to the results in this example)
traverse(node_id);
```

This gets the list of all descendant nodes.

Finally, remember that if you are lazily loading your tree, there may be nodes that are not loaded and thus their children will not feature in this list.